# Bluebird Promise Bind Chain

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird, chain

I am using Bluebird for promises and trying to allow chain calling however using .bind() doesnt seem to work. I am getting:

> TypeError: sample.testFirst(...).testSecond is not a function

The first method is called correctly and starts the promise chain but I havent been able to get the instance binding working at all.

This is my test code:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');

SampleObject = function()
{
  this._ready = this.ready();
};

SampleObject.prototype.ready = function()
{
  return new Promise(function(resolve)
  {
    resolve();
  }).bind(this);
}

SampleObject.prototype.testFirst = function()
{
  return this._ready.then(function()
  {
    console.log('test_first');
  });
}

SampleObject.prototype.testSecond = function()
{
  return this._ready.then(function()
  {
    console.log('test_second');
  });
}

var sample = new SampleObject();
sample.testFirst().testSecond().then(function()
{
  console.log('done');
});
```

I am using the latest bluebird via:

> npm install --save bluebird

Am I approaching this wrong? I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is throwing that error because, there is no method `testSecond` on `testFirst` , If you want to do something after both the Promises are resolved, do it like below :

```
var sample = new SampleObject();

Promise.join(sample.testFirst(), sample.testSecond()).spread(function (testFirst, testSecond){
  // Here testFirst is returned by resolving the promise created by `sample.testFirst` and 
  // testSecond is returned by resolving the promise created by `sample.testSecond`
});
```

If you want to check if both are resolved properly, instead of doing a console.log , return the string in `testFirst` and `testSecond` functions and log them in the `spread` callback as shown below :

```
SampleObject.prototype.testFirst = function()
{
  return this._ready.then(function()
  {
    return 'test_first';
  });
}

SampleObject.prototype.testSecond = function()
{
  return this._ready.then(function()
  {
    return 'test_second';
  });
}
```

Now, doing a `console.log` in the `spread` callback as shown below , will log the strings returned by the promises above :

```
Promise.join(sample.testFirst(), sample.testSecond()).spread(function(first, second){
  console.log(first); // test_first
  console.log(second); // test_second
});
```

Comment: My assumption was that there is only a single Promise built via ready() then each test() function is just another then() chain in the promise that continues to inherit the SampleObject for more chained calls. Is that possible?

Comment: No, each time you call `ready()` creates a new promise , you can chain each of those promises with `.then()`. And yes, each test function is another chain but you have to refer it with respect to next as I've done in my answer.

Comment: But ready() is only being called once, inside the objects constructor which returns the promise. Each test function uses then() via the already created Promise.

Comment: No. That's not how it works. Each test function is returning a new promise created in ready, ready is being called for every test function

Comment: Oh okay, makes sense. Appreciate the clarification.

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help :). Happy coding :)